# Pros and Cons of defining function inside a React component or in that file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, scope

If I have a file called `Table.jsx` that has a `class Table` component, what's the pros of having helper functions live outside of that class in that function vs. inside the class body? I feel like if it lives in the file it should be used by another component that lives in that save file, otherwise it should just live inside that component so that you can access `this.props` without having to pass it around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the most part it doesn't really matter.

There is a very slight performance gain for using pure function defined at a module level, or static methods at a class level. Class methods are created for every instance of a class, and supposedly, they are harder to optimize for browsers. A module method may be a little more inconvenient, you may have to pass props to it for instance, but browsers can do some work to optimize these methods for slight performance gains.

I don't think I've ever seen convincing evidence that this performance gain is worthwhile.

The real gain, in my opinion, is that testing functions not bound to classes are a lot easier. You can test them without instantiating a class.

Comment: `Class methods are created for every instance of a class` no they are not as long as you don't bind them

Comment: @JonasWilms what do you mean by bind them?

Comment: @stackjlei in React you'll often find `this.method = this.method.bind(this)` which binds the method to the instance and does create an overhead for every instance. As long as you don't do that there is no overhead at all

Answer (score 2):

In the component itself:

You can access `this` from inside the method. The method can't be accessed from outside the class.

Outside the component:

You can't access `this`. The function can be accessed from everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

There are both pros and cons to having methods live in or outside the component class. Ive listed a case for having it live in and outside below

Cases for having it on the outside:

- Reusable code which can be imported by components that needs the same
  function. Will reduce redundancy

Case for having it live within the component:

- If you are exporting this component to another project, if it is self contained within itself, it makes it a lot easier to consume without importing a lot of dependencies